# How to call a promise inside a observable function

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have to make two api calls, the second one expects a value that is fetched at couchDB as a promise.

The method is inherited so i can't modify it. I need the second call to wait for the promise to resolve, so i can then return the order values.

```
buscarpedidos(perfil: any, dataIni: string, dataFim: string,
   offset?: any, limit?: any): Observable<any> {
    let idIntegracaoBD = this.idIntegracaoBD();
    let db = new PouchDB(APPCONFIG.couchdb + '/marketplace');
    let result = db.get(idIntegracaoBD).then((response) =>
    {
      return this.integracaoService.buscarVendasShopeeV2(dataIni,
       dataFim, perfil.shopId, "ALL", response['shopeeV2.access_token'])
    });
    return result;
  }
```

Comment: use async await may be ? or can you please explain it further its not fully clear may be paste some more code ?

Answer (score 0):

If you wana wait for result do this

```
async buscarpedidos(perfil: any, dataIni: 
 string, dataFim: string,
 offset?: any, limit?: any): 
  Observable<any> {
   let idIntegracaoBD = 
   this.idIntegracaoBD();
   let db = new PouchDB(APPCONFIG.couchdb 
    + '/marketplace');
   let result = await 
    db.get(idIntegracaoBD)
   return result;
 }
```